# Convert string to html attributes

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

Is their a way to convert a string (this string can change and contains **asp-route-...** attributes) to a list of html attributes? The razor engine should use all the asp-route-... attributes to convert to a correct url. I have the following code but that doesn't work.

```
@{
    var Attributes     = ViewData["Attributes"] as Dictionary<string,string>;
    var AttributeRoute = "";

    @foreach (var key in Attributes.Keys)
    {
        AttributeRoute += "asp-route-"+key+"=\""+Attributes[key]+"\" ";
    }
}

...

@AttributeRoute #Prints output (ex. asp-route-testkey="testvalue")

<a class='item' @AttributeRoute>test</a> #Doesn't print the list of attributes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by doing the following:

## 1. Create custom Taghelper class

```
namespace test
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("special-link")]
    public class SpecialLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            //Create a tag
            output.TagName="a";

            //Get the parameters
            string parameters="";
            Dictionary<string,string> Parameters = (Dictionary<string,string>)this.ViewContext.ViewData["Attributes"];
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in Parameters){
                parameters+= pair.Key+"="+pair.Value+"&";
            }

            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "?"+parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

## 2. Create Link (in a .cshtml file)

```
<special-link>link</special-link>
```

Hope this can help someone!